# Change Created Date to date from field_post_date

Tags: 7, datetime, views

I am changing a large amount of news content types 'Created' dates. I figured out to use VBO with execute php and this code...

```
$entity -> created = strtotime($entity->field_post_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);
node_save($entity);
```

This code works!

Comment: So, the code above made it one day later then what is was. I found something to make it the exact correct date...   `$entity -> created = strtotime($entity->field_post_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) - 60*60*24;
node_save($entity);`

Answer (score 0):

I had 'create' not 'created' - Doh! 
Now it works...